# how can i get a hashmap to store the number of an item sold

Tags: java, android, button, hashmap

Using a hash map i need to store the number of pies sold.  I have three buttons in my android studio app, mince, steak and potatotop.  when a user clicks a button i need to update the value stored in the hashmap increasing it by one.

Comment: keep the id of producttype as id in the map, and augment the value linked to it

Comment: Get the current value from the map, increment it, and then put the new value back in the map. Make sure to handle the case where the key/value pair is not already in the map, unless you initialize the map with all keys and an appropriate default value. You can do this relatively simply using [merge](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map#merge(K,%20V,%20java.util.function.BiFunction%3C?%20super%20V,%20?%20super%20V,%20?%20extends%20V%3E)).